# How can I verify my custom domain on firebase using GoDaddy

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting, firebase-hosting

I recently created a project on firebase to host my website and I've transfered my data to their subdomain. But I want to connect my own domain ardacebi.com It gave me a TXT file to save from the DNS Manager but I can't save the file. It gives an error at the main machine part. I put the symbol @ but it ignores it.

How can I fix this problem or can you suggest me a website or tutorial (an easy one).

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the TXT records provided by Firebase in your Domain Registrar (GoDaddy in your case). You can follow the steps provided in [this link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-a-txt-record-19232) to add a TXT records in your Domain registered at GoDaddy.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works with my own domain. But I still have issues installing wordpress on my hosting. In some sources, they say that firebase doesn't support wordpress (I mean php files requires a index.html file). But is it possible with some ways?

Comment: Firebase Hosting only provides static hosting for your web app, which means it can only host your app's static assets (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc). If you want to install wordpress, then you need to host your web app on GoDaddy or any other hosting service provider.

Comment: Just to clarify... Should we set www and ftp to the firebase link that is provided?

Comment: @MichaelAustin If I understood correctly, you are asking about the entry in `HOST` field while adding new `TXT` record. In that case it is your domain name `www.example.com` that you need to write in `HOST` field. FYI you will get all the instructions while enabling Hosting in your Firebase project.

Answer (score 20):

**Add custom domain from GoDaddy to firebase hosting**

> If you are reading this answer then you are lucky that you are at the right place. At initial, I also faced difficulty but its simple and needs patience.

**Steps to add custom domain from GoDaddy to firebase hosting**

1. Go to the firebase hosting page then add a custom domain like `www.xyz.com` and definitely you want to redirect like the standard approach(xyz.com). So add and redirect like this is your output after adding and verify.

[image]

2. Go to the GoDaddy DNS page and add google verification like this. Don't follow the firebase step as it says add `www.xyz.com`.

```
Type   Host Name    Value
-----+-----------+-------------------------------------   
TXT       @         google-site-verification={ver-code}
```

and TTL to 1/2 hr then ADD. And wait for a few minutes to an hour to connect google-site-verification then click on `Verify` in the firebase hosting console.

Note: `Verify` will only work after some time.

3. Add `A` type in GoDaddy. And delete all previous `A`, `AAAA`, and `CNAME` types from Godaddy.

```
Type   Host Name    Value
-----+-----------+-------------------------------------   
 A       www        151.101.1.195
    
 A       www        151.101.65.195
```

4. Now add `xyz.com` again in firebase as a custom domain to work what you added in redirect in step 1. And this is your final view of the firebase hosting as connected in some time.
   [image]
5. Go to GoDaddy and add `A` type like this

```
Type   Host Name    Value
-----+-----------+-------------------------------------   
 A        @         151.101.1.195
    
 A        @         151.101.65.195
```

So, at last, you have this in GoDaddy.
[image]

6. Click on the finish and wait for 2-48 hours. Keep patience it will work

Comment: This is the real practical answer which works, I wasted a week hoping for verification to succeed but that only happened when I set the host to "@" .