# How can I verify my custom domain on firebase using hostgator

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

How can I verify my custom domain on **firebase** using **Hostgator**,
I used godaddy before with firebase but, Hostgator requires to change the name servers to the firebase

Comment: Can you include things you've tried? Particularly since similar questions have been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy

Comment: i used godaddy before with firebase but,hostgator requires to change name servers to firebase

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find answer for that so, I hosted the website on Hostgator and used Firebase as a Database.