# Firebase hosting not validating TXT record in GoDaddy

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I deployed my app and now I'm trying to add my custom URL.  I followed Firebase's instructions and added their TXT record to my DNS (GoDaddy).  But now Firebase is saying it's still not verified.  I assume I'm doing something wrong, but there's not much here to mess up...

[image: Screen Shot of Firebase]

[image: Screen shot of DNS]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it even matters, not an expert in this area... but in the past I've always used `@` in the `Name` column in GoDaddy, not the actual name of the domain I own. Maybe try that?

Comment: Yep!  That solved it!!  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Step-by-step solutions with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Per my comment above, the solution was to use the `@` sign in the `Name` column of GoDaddy, not the actual name of the domain that is owned.

Comment: Was after this for 2 hours. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me.   @ for the name for the TXT file

and @

for a redirect from www.yourdomain.com to yourdomain.com in the

A file

Comment: adding CNAME www mytestapp.firebaseapp.com ttll:1 Hour is not needed?

Comment: All step-by-step solutions with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369

Answer (score 29):

To add a bit more information to this great solution for future reference.

DNS propagation can be monitored using a service like:
https://www.whatsmydns.net/
This will show you when your records are ready, thus can be verified by firebase.

As for subdomain, ie.
beta.example.com

The value would be 'beta' instead of '@' or 'example.com' for the godaddy DNS records.

Comment: Pointing to ```whatsmydns.net``` was useful for me - waiting for my TXT to appear - https://www.whatsmydns.net/#TXT/example.com

Comment: Do you enter your firebase domain name or godaddy new domain name?

Comment: You shall enter the godaddy new domain in the tool to see how it propagate via DNS servers.

Answer (score 9):

TXT GoDaddy TTL time is approximately 2 hours, Please re-verify after  2 hour firebase.

Answer (score 7):

I see you fixed your problem but for anyone trying to link their godaddy domain with the reset password/ verify email service in Firebase Auth you need to remove your domain name from the CNAME record name.

Firebase gave me `firebase2._domainkey.mydomain.com` and in godaddy CNAME record name I only used `firebase2._domainkey` and it verified my domain.

Comment: do this for your firebase1._domainkey as well! :)

Comment: If anybody see's this and is using google domains, make sure you do this ^^^.
Google domains automatically appends your domain to the end, so my CNAME name was always `firebase2._domainkey.mydomain.com.mydomain.com` and I did not realise.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have to set up the acme-challenge for your https certificate you probably may get something like this:

_acme-challenge.domain.com

just remove domain.com

in the case, you might have a subdomain
_acme-challenge.subdomain.domain.com
change it only to
_acme-challenge.subdomain

it will work in a couple of hours

Answer (score 0):

For **TXT** records use @ for host instead of mysite.com

and for

**A** record, if it is subdomain, just add subdomain in the place of host. for example, https://**subdomain**.mysite.com => just add "**subdomain**" in Host of your DNS records in godaddy.