# Godaddy Custom Domain | Firebase Website | Site can't be reached

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I have purchased a domain from Godaddy let's say myCustomDomainName.com

I have created a project and deployed a web page in FireBase - https://home-myCustomDomainName.firebaseapp.com/

I have linked a custom domain in the project console 
[image]

In GoDaddy the A records and TXT Records are also updated.
[image]

The site was up for a while. I could access my website using https://myCustomDomainName.com as well as https://www.myCustomDomainName.com

But now I keep getting Site can't be reached error. [I am however able to reach the site through firebase URL https://home-myCustomDomainName.firebaseapp.com/]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg3NW.png)

Even ping requests fail.
[image]

Please advice on what could be wrong and how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the www and the .com and use @ or your sub host

e.g.

example.com:

Type: A, Value:@, IP: x.y.z.a

subdomain.example.com 
Type: A, Name:subdomain, IP: x.y.z.a

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to access my site through both https://myCustomDomainName.com and https://www.myCustomDomainName.com

Comment: So you've fixed it now?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Simple step-by-step solutions with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369