# How to use Firebase Hosting by providing the Nameserver over TXT value?

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting, firebase-hosting, nameservers

I do not have access to the GoDaddy account and am not too familiar with hosting in general. I'm trying to use Firebase hosting for a domain that is already purchased.  I provided the TXT value to the manager of the GoDaddy account but he does not have access to add the record.  He wants me to provide the nameserver instead.  Is there a way to get this value from Firebase?

I'm not fully sure what the nameserver is so not sure how that can show ownership for the Firebase hosting so not sure if I'm missing something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the name server is the next step, which can only be taken after you verify ownership of the domain. And verifying ownership requires that you add a TXT record to your DNS record.

You might want to point your hosting manager to the [GoDaddy documentation on adding TXT records](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-txt-record-19232) or [How can I verify my custom domain on firebase using GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy) (which I actually now realize your question is a duplicate of).

Comment: Thank you. The manager of the GoDaddy account changed settings on his end.