# Mapping GoDaddy domain to Firebase Hosting does not get verified

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm probably doing something silly, but I can't seem to be able to figure this out.

I've waited over 24 hours for Firebase to validate my domain, but the status just stays at "needs setup" and "domain not verified".

Per other other related answers on StackOverflow, I use @ as the Name for TXT, instead of what Firebase said to put there (I also tried the "acme-challenge.www.mydomain.com" for a while).

Here are my GoDaddy records:

[image]

Anyone got ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Simple step-by-step solutions with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I think I got to the bottom of it finally (I'm really new to this domain business). I originally added `www.mydomain.com` and not the naked `mydomain.com` to the "connect domain wizard". And I believe since I didn't have a CNAME www pointing to @ it could never have worked.

Now I just added `mydomain.com` to the wizard, and Firebase instantly validated the domain.

The status is now "pending" since it takes up to 24 hours to validate the certificate, but the site already works.

Comment: Simple step by step solution with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to delete the original `A` records using the name `@`. Only keep the `A` records that are pointing to the Firebase Hosting IP address.

**EDIT:**
Change your `TXT` value to `google-site-verification=YOURCODE`.

It must include `google-site-verification=`.

Comment: I should've mentioned that they are pointing to the Firebase IP addresses.

Comment: Do you have any other conflicting `A` records? You should only have two that use the `@` name.

Comment: No. All four of them point to Firebase IPs. And the last two of the A records in the screenshot are the result of adding a redirection from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com - as instructed by the Firebase wizard.

Comment: Try changing your `TXT` file to `google-site-verification=YOURCODE`. That's how mine is set up.

Comment: Well, I did this a few hours ago, but no change yet. Let's see a bit later, if it just takes some time.

Comment: how can I find YOURCODE?

Answer (score 0):

**Add custom domain from GoDaddy to firebase hosting**

> Simple step-by-step solutions with screenshots are found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369)