# Attaching Godaddy domain name to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Why this is showing in firebase hosting that my Go daddy domain name may be connected with another project.

I have not connected my domain name with any project.

Now when my i am trying to connect my Ho daddy domain name with the hosting of firebase. It's not getting connected.

Please somebody help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not going to be able to help you with your DNS configuration.  You should reach out to Firebase support directly. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please find step-by-step solutions with screenshots here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369